# git clone→docker composeでコンテナが起動せず1行のエラーのみ返ってくる

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

会社のリポジトリで、いつも通りcloneしてdockerを立ち上げました。
しかし下記のエラー1行のみ返ってくるだけで、進みません。

```
line 1: unexpected character "\x00" in variable name
```

情報が少なすぎて、そもそも何を確認したら良いか分からない状況です。
ヒントを探すために何をすればよいか、教えていただけないでしょうか？

Comment: Git を使っているなら、正常な状態のコミットとの差分を確認することはできませんか？

Comment: docker 自体は立ち上げるものではないのでおそらく docker run か docker compose up をなさったのだと思いますが、Dockerfile か docker-compose.yml の情報がないと答えづらいです。